# How do I set the isolation level of transaction of Postgres from Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, isolation-level

I have some stored procedures, and I have a class through which I call them.But before I call them I want to change the isolation level from the read commited to repeatable read in the class trough which I call them (or) while establishing a connection to the database(not sure if its possible)(in java) using the Postgres jdbc.
I tought I could establish the isolation level in the stored procedures themselves,but after some looking around,I found that its out of question.
So how do I mention the isolation levels from the java side before calling the procedures?

I know in psql I would do the following :

```
set transaction isolation level repeatable read;
begin transaction
--my transactions begin...--
```

Sorry if this is a naive question,but I havn't been able to find an answer to my question.

EDIT__

I call my stored procedure by the following

```
String query = String.format("SELECT create_queue('%s')", queueName);

        st = connection.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

create_queue is my stored procedure.

Comment: How do you call your stored procedures?

Comment: @Kayaman I have edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Connection::setTransactionIsolation`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setTransactionIsolation-int-